# Can't Find a "Most Popular Tags" Hack Anywhere

Tags: tags, hacks

If anybody knows where to find a most popular tags hack, I would be forever grateful.  I've searched and searched to no avail.

Comment: The WordPress Tag Cloud? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/most-popular-tags/

And/ or

see this codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_tag_cloud

Answer (score 1):

This was the first Stackoverflow answer when I Googled this so for other people use:

```
$tags = get_terms( 'post_tag', array(
     'orderby' => 'count',
     'order' => 'DESC'
) );
```

No need for a plugin for this simple task.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms